# AngularJS select tag binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I am trying to build a check out mechanism where the shipping prices are calculated according to country. If the user selects United States it should return US. If the user selects any other country it should return Not US

the shipping function returns US as the select option is in United States. But when an another country gets selected, the function still returns US .

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("CartApp", ['ngCookies']);
app.controller("CartForm", function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
    var shipping = 0;
    $scope.shipping = function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("countries").value;
        if (e == 'United States') {
            shipping = 1;
            return "US";
        } else if (e != 'United States') {
            shipping = 4;
            return "Not US";
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="CartApp">
    <div ng-controller="CartForm">{{shipping()}}
        <select id="countries" name="countries">
            <option selected="selected" value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the code, it does not return US, rather nothing is returned. Try using ng-watch on the select tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to mix two different data binding mechanisms.
Just picking up AngularJS, this seems to be the same algorithm without using getElementById()

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [ 'United States'
    , 
      'Albania'
    , 
      'Algeria'
    ];
    $scope.shipping = $scope.countries[0];
    $scope.isUS = function () {
        if ($scope.shipping == 'United States') {
            return 'US';
        } else {
            return 'Non US';
        }
    };
});


<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <div>User selected: {{shipping}}</div>
        <div> Is US? {{isUS()}}</div>
        <select ng-model="shipping" ng-options="c for c in countries"></select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. I am trying to build a check out mechanism where the shipping prices are calculated according to country. If the user selects United States it should return US. If the user selects any other country it should return Not US

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7W88e/ i am not too sure if this is working. probably my bad. could you check the fiddle?

Comment: Your fiddle didn't activate angular. You might want to  check your code to see if it is executing.  Please accept the answer if it is correct.